# ember cli pagination как должен работать

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Всем привет. Подскажите как правильно установить  [ember-cli-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-pagination), что бы он работал.

У меня есть роут:

```js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    controller: null,
    setupController:function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        this.set('controller',controller );
        controller.getData()
    },

    beforeModel: function() {},

    perPage: 25,

    model: function(params) {

        return App.New.create({
            statuses:[
                {id:1, text: "purpose of courier"},
                {id:2, text: "Courier Appointed"},
                {id:3, text: "On the way to the restaurant"},
                {id:4, text: "Arrived at the restaurant"},
                {id:5, text: "On the way to the customer"},
                {id:6, text: "Arrived to the customer"},
                {id:7, text: "Fulfilled"},
                {id:8, text: "Canceled"},
                {id:9, text: "Removed"}
            ],
            loaderMain:false,
            result: [],
            count: 0
        });
    },
    afterModel: function () {
        //this.refresh();
    }



});
```

Парамет result получаю аяксом и изменяю в контроллере.

Есть шаблон:

```
{{#each model.result as |order index|}}
 ....
{{/each}}

{{page-numbers content=model.result}}
```

**Как "заставить" его работать с параметром model.result в данном случае?**

**Как изменить код так, что бы по клику на след страницу вызывать  controller.getData() ?**

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае Вам необходимо создавать и хранить модели в `this.storage`. По моему мнению в данном случае уж лучше использовать простой [ember-simple-pagination](https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-simple-pagination) вместо  ember-cli-pagination

Установка

```
ember install ember-simple-pagination
```

template

```
{{simple-pagination 
 recordCount=model.count
 pageSize=model.pageSize 
 pageNumber=model.pageNumber
 onPageSelect=(action "getPage")}}
```

Ну а к контроллере уже action задаёте и изменяете параметры

Comment: Спасибо, помогло